# Use cases for Scala's Actors in a SavingsBankAccount program

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

This is not an assignment of any kind. I am in the process of learning Scala and Scala concurrency preferably with Akka Actors. One of the ways I am doing this is by coming up with some simple program design and trying to come up an implementation that involves Actors/concurrency applied to the design:

The program I want to write is a Savings Bank Account Application that has an input component and an output component. 
 **Bank XYZ is offering to customers a scheme to open Savings Account**
 
 1) customer ABC is asked to provide his personal details when he/she is opening the account
 
 2) the customer can them deposit money into his/her account
 
 3) the customer can withdraw money from his/her account

 4) If the account balance falls below $100, the customer is notified. (For example, when the customer chooses Option 3 from the input screen of the application, he/she is informed that the account balance at that time is below $100, so withdrawal is not possible, unless they deposit more money into it.)
  
 5) the application should be able to maintain the customer's transaction history and also display the transaction history (for example: when the application presents the input screen, one of the options is - Display Transaction History. When this option is selected with a number when prompted, the application should display a Balance)
 
 The input part of the program consists of 4 options that are presented on the command line: 1. Create Account 2. Deposit Money 3. Withdraw Money. 4. Display Transaction History

---

Now, what I am trying to accomplish for now is to understand and identify: 
1) What can be a use-case for Akka actors/Scala concurrency libraries in such a program? What if any can be the role(s) for concurrency in this application?

 What Scala collection libraries can I best leverage?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves the problem: 
http://alexminnaar.com/introduction-to-the-multithreading-problem-and-the-akka-actor-solution.html

Note: I just noticed that this post is old. I am posting answer in 2018.

Update1: (Explanation from link, after mentioned in comments)

This is one approach among multiple possible strategies.

There are two Actors used

1. BankAccount - To manage balance

   ```
       object WireTransfer {

       case class Transfer(from: ActorRef, to: ActorRef, amount: BigInt)

       case object Done

       case object Failed

       }

       //actor implementing the actions of a wire transfer between two bank account actors
       class WireTransfer extends Actor {

       import WireTransfer._

       def receive = LoggingReceive {
       //If Transfer message is received, send withdraw message to 'from' and wait for reply
       case Transfer(from, to, amount) =>
       from ! BankAccount.Withdraw(amount)
       context.become(awaitFrom(to, amount, sender))
       }

       //If Withdraw was successful, send deposit to other bank account actor, or else give them a failure message
       def awaitFrom(to: ActorRef, amount: BigInt, customer: ActorRef): Receive = LoggingReceive {
       case BankAccount.Done =>
       to ! BankAccount.Deposit(amount)
       context.become(awaitTo(customer))
       case BankAccount.Failed =>
       customer ! Failed
       context.stop(self)
       }

       //If deposit was successful, send 'Done' to original actor that sent Transfer message
       def awaitTo(customer: ActorRef): Receive = LoggingReceive {
       case BankAccount.Done =>
       customer ! Done
       context.stop(self)
       }
       }
   ```
2. WireTransfer - To transfer the balance from one account to another.

   ```
       object WireTransfer {

       case class Transfer(from: ActorRef, to: ActorRef, amount: BigInt)

       case object Done

       case object Failed

       }

       //actor implementing the actions of a wire transfer between two bank account actors
       class WireTransfer extends Actor {

       import WireTransfer._

       def receive = LoggingReceive {
       //If Transfer message is received, send withdraw message to 'from' and wait for reply
       case Transfer(from, to, amount) =>
       from ! BankAccount.Withdraw(amount)
       context.become(awaitFrom(to, amount, sender))
       }

       //If Withdraw was successful, send deposit to other bank account actor, or else give them a failure message
       def awaitFrom(to: ActorRef, amount: BigInt, customer: ActorRef): Receive = LoggingReceive {
       case BankAccount.Done =>
       to ! BankAccount.Deposit(amount)
       context.become(awaitTo(customer))
       case BankAccount.Failed =>
       customer ! Failed
       context.stop(self)
       }

       //If deposit was successful, send 'Done' to original actor that sent Transfer message
       def awaitTo(customer: ActorRef): Receive = LoggingReceive {
       case BankAccount.Done =>
       customer ! Done
       context.stop(self)
       }
       }
   ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20023980)

Comment: Acknowledged! Thank you. I will keep that in mind for next. I am fairly new here.